# Maven incremental compilation for tests only

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin, incremental-build

I know, that by using the `useIncrementalCompilation` parameter, it's possible to enable incremental compilation, for example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But in this case, both classes in `src` and `tests` are compiled incrementally.
I would like it to be for tests only. Is it possible?

My environment:

- Java 1.8
- Apache Maven 3.8.2
- maven-compiler-plugin 3.1

I'm build project by this way: `mvn clean install`

Maybe there is some plugin that would allow me to compile tests (tests only) incrementally?

Comment: Even if you could, the whole feature is pretty much broken anyway. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-205

Comment: Can you tell us how you call Maven? Which JDK version and which Maven version and plugins versions you are using etc. ?

Comment: Yes, of course, I will update my question now.

Comment: First I strongly recommend to upgrade your maven-compiler-plugin version because the one your are using is about 8 years old... Please check: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/